# tabular as matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

I have the attached figure and I need to have arrows from the entries of the table on the right-hand-side (one which says Dimensions List DL) to nodes of the tree.

I think the best way to do this is to define the table as a matrix of nodes rather than as tabular, but I could not get it to work and would appreciate any assistance.

I would like to be able to specify the table to be to the right of node N11 (perhaps with some x,y coordinate adjustment). Here is the code I have and the figure generated following it.

```
![\documentclass{scrartcl}      % KOMA script (my preference)

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz-rdf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.callouts,,decorations.text,shapes.misc,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes.geometric,backgrounds,fit,positioning,arrows}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure*}\[ht!\]%
          \begin{minipage}\[c\]{0.7\textwidth}
    \centering
    \scalebox{.5}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}\[node distance=1.5cm, every edge/.style={link}\]
%
%Inserting nodes N1-N3
%    
        \node\[circle,draw\] (n0){$N_{0}$};
        \node\[circle,draw\] (n1)\[below left=of n0\]{$N_{1}$};
        \node\[circle,draw\] (n2)\[below left=of n1\]{$N_{2}$};
        \node\[circle,draw\] (n3)\[below left=of n2\]{$N_{3}$};
            \node\[circle,draw\] (n4)\[below left=of n3\]{$N_{4}$};
        \node\[circle,draw\] (n5)\[below right=of n2\]{$N_{5}$};
            \node\[circle,draw\] (n8)\[below right=of n0\]{$N_{8}$};
            \node\[circle,draw\] (n11)\[below right=of n0,xshift=1.5cm\]{$N_{11}$};
            \node\[circle,draw\] (n6)\[below right=of n1\]{$N_{6}$};
            \node\[circle,draw\] (n7)\[below right=of n6\]{$N_{7}$};
        \node\[circle,draw\] (n9)\[below right=of n8\]{$N_{9}$};
            \node\[circle,draw\] (n10)\[below =of n9\]{$N_{10}$};
            \node\[circle,draw\] (n12)\[below right=of n11\]{$N_{12}$};
%
%Inserting edges
%    
        \draw\[-\] (n0) -- (n1);
        \draw\[-\] (n1) -- (n2);
        \draw\[-\] (n2) -- (n3);
        \draw\[-\] (n3) -- (n4);
            \draw\[-\] (n2) -- (n5);
            \draw\[-\] (n0) -- (n8);
            \draw\[-\] (n0) -- (n11);
            \draw\[-\] (n1) -- (n6);
            \draw\[-\] (n6) -- (n7);
            \draw\[-\] (n8) -- (n9);
            \draw\[-\] (n9) -- (n10);
            \draw\[-\] (n11) -- (n12);    
%
%Inserting node labels
%    
        \node\[rectangle\] (root)\[above left=of n0,xshift=1cm,yshift=-1.3cm\]{root};
        \node\[rectangle\] (salary)\[above left=of n1,xshift=1cm,yshift=-1.3cm\]{salary};
        \node\[rectangle\] (gender)\[above left=of n2,xshift=1cm,yshift=-1.3cm\]{gender};
        \node\[rectangle\] (title)\[above left=of n3,xshift=1cm,yshift=-1.3cm\]{title};
            \node\[rectangle\] (nat)\[above left=of n4,xshift=1cm,yshift=-1.3cm\]{nationality};
            \node\[rectangle\] (nat1)\[below=of n5,yshift=1.3cm\]{nationality};
            \node\[rectangle\] (title2)\[above left=of n6,xshift=1cm,yshift=-1.3cm\]{title};
            \node\[rectangle\] (nat2)\[below=of n7,yshift=1.3cm\]{nationality};
            \node\[rectangle\] (year)\[above left=of n8,xshift=1cm,yshift=-1.3cm\]{year};
            \node\[rectangle\] (inPr)\[above left=of n9,xshift=1cm,yshift=-1.3cm\]{inProceedings};
            \node\[rectangle\] (papT)\[below right=of n10,yshift=1.3cm,xshift=-1cm\]{paperTitle};
            \node\[rectangle\] (loc)\[above =of n11,yshift=-1.3cm\]{locatedIn};
        \node\[rectangle\] (name)\[below=of n12,yshift=1.3cm\]{name};
%
%Dimension list and the links to T-tree
%
        \scalebox{1.1}{
        \node (dl) \[right=of n11,xshift=2cm,yshift=-1.5cm,rectangle split, 
                              rectangle split parts=9, draw,align=center,anchor=center\]{%
            salary\nodepart{two}gender\nodepart{three}title\nodepart{four}nationality
                    \nodepart{five}year\nodepart{six}inProceedings\nodepart{seven}paperTitle
            \nodepart{eight}locatedIn\nodepart{nine}name
            };

        }
        \node(dlhead)\[above=of dl,xshift=0.7cm,yshift=-1.7cm\] {\large{$\begin{array}{c} \textrm{Dimension}\\\textrm{List }DL\end{array}$}};

    \draw\[->,dashed,red\]   (dl.text) to \[out=170, in= 90\] (n1);%from salary
    \draw\[->,dashed,red\] (dl.two) to \[out=170, in= 90\] (n2); %from gender
    \draw\[->,dashed,red\] (dl.three) to \[bend right\] (n3); %from title
    \draw\[->,dashed,red\] (dl.four) to \[bend right\] (n4.15); %from nationality
    \draw\[->,dashed,red\] (dl.five) to \[bend right\] (n8); %from year
    \draw\[->,dashed,red\] (dl.six) to \[bend right\] (n9); %from inProceedings
    \draw\[->,dashed,red\] (dl.seven) to (n10); %from paperTItle
    \draw\[->,dashed,red\] (dl.eight) to (n11); %from locatedIn
    \draw\[->,dashed,red\] (dl.nine) -- (n12); %from name
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
      \end{minipage}
 \caption{T-index}%
  \vspace{-0.2in}
 \label{fig:star}
\end{figure*}



\end{document}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although a matrix of nodes is an option, it is much simpler to use a multipart rectangle (See Section **48.6 Shapes with Multiple Text Parts** of the pgf manual):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}        % KOMA script (my preference)

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{tikz-rdf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.callouts,,decorations.text,shapes.misc,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes.geometric,backgrounds,fit,positioning,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[ht!]%
\vspace{-0.2in}
%   \centering
%   \subfigure[b][{ Transaction Database $D$}]{%
%      \includegraphics[scale=0.50]{newpics/DB.pdf}
    \subfloat[\scriptsize Transaction Database $D$]{
      \begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \scalebox{.7}{
    \begin{tabular}{| p{1cm} | p{1.5cm} | p{4cm} |}\hline
        Vertex ID & Entity \mbox{vertex} &  Adjacent Attribute Properties \\ \hline \hline
        001 & Person1 & salary, gender, title \\ \hline
        002 & Person2 & salary, gender, title, nationality \\ \hline
        003 & Person3 & salary, gender, title \\ \hline
        004 & Person4 & salary, gender, title, nationality \\ \hline
        005 & Person5 & salary, gender, nationality \\ \hline
        006 & Person6 & salary, title, nationality \\ \hline
        007 & Paper1 & year, inProceedings, paperTitle \\ \hline
        008 & Paper2 & year, inProceedings, paperTitle \\ \hline
        009 & Paper3 & year, inProceedings, paperTitle \\ \hline
        010 & School1 & locatedIn, name \\ \hline
        011 & School2 & locatedIn, name \\ \hline
        012 & School3 & locatedIn, name \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    }
      \end{minipage}
       \label{fig:db}%
       }%
%
%   \subfigure[b][{T-Index}]{%
%      \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{newpics/FPtree.pdf}
    \subfloat[\scriptsize T-Index]{
          \begin{minipage}[c]{0.7\textwidth}
    \centering
    \scalebox{.5}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm, every edge/.style={link}]
%
%Inserting nodes N1-N3
%    
        \node[circle,draw] (n0){$N_{0}$};
        \node[circle,draw] (n1)[below left=of n0]{$N_{1}$};
        \node[circle,draw] (n2)[below left=of n1]{$N_{2}$};
        \node[circle,draw] (n3)[below left=of n2]{$N_{3}$};
            \node[circle,draw] (n4)[below left=of n3]{$N_{4}$};
        \node[circle,draw] (n5)[below right=of n2]{$N_{5}$};
            \node[circle,draw] (n8)[below right=of n0]{$N_{8}$};
            \node[circle,draw] (n11)[below right=of n0,xshift=1.5cm]{$N_{11}$};
            \node[circle,draw] (n6)[below right=of n1]{$N_{6}$};
            \node[circle,draw] (n7)[below right=of n6]{$N_{7}$};
        \node[circle,draw] (n9)[below right=of n8]{$N_{9}$};
            \node[circle,draw] (n10)[below =of n9]{$N_{10}$};
            \node[circle,draw] (n12)[below right=of n11]{$N_{12}$};
%
%Inserting edges
%    
        \draw[-] (n0) -- (n1);
        \draw[-] (n1) -- (n2);
        \draw[-] (n2) -- (n3);
        \draw[-] (n3) -- (n4);
            \draw[-] (n2) -- (n5);
            \draw[-] (n0) -- (n8);
            \draw[-] (n0) -- (n11);
            \draw[-] (n1) -- (n6);
            \draw[-] (n6) -- (n7);
            \draw[-] (n8) -- (n9);
            \draw[-] (n9) -- (n10);
            \draw[-] (n11) -- (n12);    
%
%Inserting node labels
%    
        \node[rectangle] (root)[above left=of n0,xshift=1cm,yshift=-1.3cm]{root};
        \node[rectangle] (salary)[above left=of n1,xshift=1cm,yshift=-1.3cm]{salary};
        \node[rectangle] (gender)[above left=of n2,xshift=1cm,yshift=-1.3cm]{gender};
        \node[rectangle] (title)[above left=of n3,xshift=1cm,yshift=-1.3cm]{title};
            \node[rectangle] (nat)[above left=of n4,xshift=1cm,yshift=-1.3cm]{nationality};
            \node[rectangle] (nat1)[below=of n5,yshift=1.3cm]{nationality};
            \node[rectangle] (title2)[above left=of n6,xshift=1cm,yshift=-1.3cm]{title};
            \node[rectangle] (nat2)[below=of n7,yshift=1.3cm]{nationality};
            \node[rectangle] (year)[above left=of n8,xshift=1cm,yshift=-1.3cm]{year};
            \node[rectangle] (inPr)[above left=of n9,xshift=1cm,yshift=-1.3cm]{inProceedings};
            \node[rectangle] (papT)[below right=of n10,yshift=1.3cm,xshift=-1cm]{paperTitle};
            \node[rectangle] (loc)[above =of n11,yshift=-1.3cm]{locatedIn};
        \node[rectangle] (name)[below=of n12,yshift=1.3cm]{name};
%
%Entering the L values
%    
        \node[rectangle] (n1b)[above left=of salary,xshift=2cm,yshift=-1.3cm]{\{001,002,003,004,005,006\}};
        \node[rectangle] (n2b)[above left=of gender,xshift=2cm,yshift=-1.3cm]{\{001,002,003,004,005\}};
        \node[rectangle] (n3b)[above left=of title,xshift=2cm,yshift=-1.3cm]{\{001,002,003,004\}};
            \node[rectangle] (n4b)[above =of nat,yshift=-1.7cm]{\{002,004\}};
            \node[rectangle] (n4b1)[below=of nat1,yshift=1.5cm]{\{005\}};
            \node[rectangle] (n6b)[above left=of title2,xshift=1.5cm,yshift=-1.3cm]{\{006\}};
            \node[rectangle] (n7b)[below=of nat2,yshift=1.5cm]{\{006\}};
            \node[rectangle] (n8b)[above left=of year,xshift=1.5cm,yshift=-1.3cm]{\{007,008,009\}};
            \node[rectangle] (n9b)[above left=of inPr,xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-1.3cm]{\{007,008,009\}};
            \node[rectangle] (n10b)[below=of papT,yshift=1.5cm]{\{007,008,009\}};
            \node[rectangle] (n11b)[above=of loc,yshift=-1.6cm]{\{010,011,012\}};
            \node[rectangle] (n12b)[below=of name,yshift=1.5cm]{\{010,011,012\}};
%
%Node-node links
%
        \draw[-,green!50!black] (n4) -- (n5);
        \draw[-,green!50!black] (n5) -- (n7);
        \draw[-,green!50!black] (n3) -- (n6);
        \draw[-,green!50!black] (n4) -- (n7);
%
%M(N3)
%
            \node (tbl) [above left=of n0,xshift=1cm]{
            \begin{tabular}{| c  | c | p{2cm} | c |} \hline
            salary & gender & title & $L$ \\ \hline
            \$100,000 & Male & Professor & \{002\} \\ \hline
            \$50,000 & Male & Assistant Professor & \{001\}  \\ \hline
            \$40,000 & Male & Assistant Professor &\{003\}  \\ \hline
            \$50,000 & Female & Assistant Professor & \{004\}  \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
        };
%
%M(N4)
%
        \node (tbl2) [below right=of n4,xshift=-1.5cm]{
            \begin{tabular}{| c  | c  | c | p{2cm} | c |} \hline
            salary & gender & title & nationality & $L$ \\ \hline
            \$45,000 & Female & Assistant Professor & Canadian & \{004\} \\ \hline
            \$100,000 & Male &  Professor & American & \{002\} \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
        };

        \node(head1)[above=of tbl,,xshift=-2.7cm,yshift=-1.7cm] {\large{$M(N_{3})$}};
        \node(head2)[above=of tbl2,,xshift=-4.3cm,yshift=-1.7cm] {\large{$M(N_{4})$}};

        \draw[->] (n3) -- (tbl.south);
        \draw[->] (n4) -- (tbl2.north);

% The Dimensions DL multipart rectangle
       \scalebox{1.1}{
        \node (dl) [right=of n11,xshift=2cm,rectangle split, 
                              rectangle split parts=9, draw,align=center,anchor=center]
            {salary\nodepart{two}gender\nodepart{three}title\nodepart{four}nationality
             \nodepart{five}year\nodepart{six}inProceedings\nodepart{seven}paperTitle
              \nodepart{eight}locatedIn\nodepart{nine}name
            };
        }
        \node (dlhead) [above=of dl,xshift=0.7cm,yshift=-1.4cm,align=center,font=\large] 
        {Dimension\\List $DL$};

% connecting some elements od Dimensions DL to the tree:
      \draw[->,shorten >= 8pt] (n0) -- (dl.text);
      \draw[->,shorten >= 12pt] (n11) -- (dl.three);
      \draw[->,shorten >= -18pt] (n12) -- (dl.nine west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
      \end{minipage}
       \label{fig:fp}%
       }%
%       \vspace{-0.2in}
 \caption{T-index}%
  \vspace{-0.2in}
 \label{fig:star}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The new problem mentioned in the edit to the original question comes from the use of \scalebox; remove this command and use, for example, the text=\Large option:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}      % KOMA script (my preference)

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{tikz-rdf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.callouts,,decorations.text,shapes.misc,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes.geometric,backgrounds,fit,positioning,arrows}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure*}[ht!]%
          \begin{minipage}[c]{0.7\textwidth}
    \centering
    \scalebox{.5}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm, every edge/.style={link}]
%
%Inserting nodes N1-N3
%    
        \node[circle,draw] (n0){$N_{0}$};
        \node[circle,draw] (n1)[below left=of n0]{$N_{1}$};
        \node[circle,draw] (n2)[below left=of n1]{$N_{2}$};
        \node[circle,draw] (n3)[below left=of n2]{$N_{3}$};
            \node[circle,draw] (n4)[below left=of n3]{$N_{4}$};
        \node[circle,draw] (n5)[below right=of n2]{$N_{5}$};
            \node[circle,draw] (n8)[below right=of n0]{$N_{8}$};
            \node[circle,draw] (n11)[below right=of n0,xshift=1.5cm]{$N_{11}$};
            \node[circle,draw] (n6)[below right=of n1]{$N_{6}$};
            \node[circle,draw] (n7)[below right=of n6]{$N_{7}$};
        \node[circle,draw] (n9)[below right=of n8]{$N_{9}$};
            \node[circle,draw] (n10)[below =of n9]{$N_{10}$};
            \node[circle,draw] (n12)[below right=of n11]{$N_{12}$};
%
%Inserting edges
%    
        \draw[-] (n0) -- (n1);
        \draw[-] (n1) -- (n2);
        \draw[-] (n2) -- (n3);
        \draw[-] (n3) -- (n4);
            \draw[-] (n2) -- (n5);
            \draw[-] (n0) -- (n8);
            \draw[-] (n0) -- (n11);
            \draw[-] (n1) -- (n6);
            \draw[-] (n6) -- (n7);
            \draw[-] (n8) -- (n9);
            \draw[-] (n9) -- (n10);
            \draw[-] (n11) -- (n12);    
%
%Inserting node labels
%    
        \node[rectangle] (root)[above left=of n0,xshift=1cm,yshift=-1.3cm]{root};
        \node[rectangle] (salary)[above left=of n1,xshift=1cm,yshift=-1.3cm]{salary};
        \node[rectangle] (gender)[above left=of n2,xshift=1cm,yshift=-1.3cm]{gender};
        \node[rectangle] (title)[above left=of n3,xshift=1cm,yshift=-1.3cm]{title};
            \node[rectangle] (nat)[above left=of n4,xshift=1cm,yshift=-1.3cm]{nationality};
            \node[rectangle] (nat1)[below=of n5,yshift=1.3cm]{nationality};
            \node[rectangle] (title2)[above left=of n6,xshift=1cm,yshift=-1.3cm]{title};
            \node[rectangle] (nat2)[below=of n7,yshift=1.3cm]{nationality};
            \node[rectangle] (year)[above left=of n8,xshift=1cm,yshift=-1.3cm]{year};
            \node[rectangle] (inPr)[above left=of n9,xshift=1cm,yshift=-1.3cm]{inProceedings};
            \node[rectangle] (papT)[below right=of n10,yshift=1.3cm,xshift=-1cm]{paperTitle};
            \node[rectangle] (loc)[above =of n11,yshift=-1.3cm]{locatedIn};
        \node[rectangle] (name)[below=of n12,yshift=1.3cm]{name};
%
%Dimension list and the links to T-tree
%

        \node (dl) [right=of n11,xshift=2cm,yshift=-1.5cm,rectangle split, 
                              rectangle split parts=9, draw,align=center,font=\Large]{%
            salary\nodepart{two}gender\nodepart{three}title\nodepart{four}nationality
                    \nodepart{five}year\nodepart{six}inProceedings\nodepart{seven}paperTitle
            \nodepart{eight}locatedIn\nodepart{nine}name
            };

          \node(dlhead)[above=of dl,yshift=-1.7cm] {\large{$\begin{array}{c} \textrm{Dimension}\\\textrm{List }DL\end{array}$}};

    \draw[->,dashed,red]   (dl.text west) to [out=170, in= 90] (n1);%from salary
    \draw[->,dashed,red] (dl.two west) to [out=170, in= 90] (n2); %from gender
    \draw[->,dashed,red] (dl.three west) to [bend right] (n3); %from title
    \draw[->,dashed,red] (dl.four west) to [bend right] (n4.15); %from nationality
    \draw[->,dashed,red] (dl.five west) to [bend right] (n8); %from year
    \draw[->,dashed,red] (dl.six west) to [bend right] (n9); %from inProceedings
    \draw[->,dashed,red] (dl.seven west) to (n10); %from paperTItle
    \draw[->,dashed,red] (dl.eight west) to (n11); %from locatedIn
    \draw[->,dashed,red] (dl.nine west) -- (n12); %from name
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
      \end{minipage}
 \caption{T-index}%
  \vspace{-0.2in}
 \label{fig:star}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this; I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Actually, I have noticed a problem in that the arrows do not start from the right table entry in each case (some are fine) and they don't go to the correct node. I have simplified the code by removing the unnecessary parts and edited my entry and I have also uploaded a new figure that shows the wrong arrows. Any suggestions as to why this might be happening?

Comment: @ozsu: problem solved; see my updated answer. A suggestion: if you have a follow-up question, add this new question to the previous one instead of deleting the original; this way, the question remains clear for other people.

Comment: Thank you very much; this is beautiful. The reason I changed the question is because someone yesterday asked me to simplify my example (regarding another question) so I thought I would simplify this one as well. In any case, your help is very much appreciated.